# Magento REST without oAuth

Tags: api, rest-api, mobile, android

I have an Android and an iOS app that connect to Magento through SOAP and perform various actions.

I have to switch to REST, but the users of the apps must not notice this change. They do not know what's behind the apps. Because Magento uses oAuth for REST, the users would have to authorize the applications. This is not desired.

I see 3 ways to go around this:

1. Use some hardcoded access tokens in the apps - looks very unsafe and I don't know if it is possible.
2. Simulate the whole oAuth process in the background - I don't know if this is possible either
3. Use the Guest role to signup/login users and then implement some kind of security token (as it is in SOAP)

I am not that experienced with webservices and I have no idea which way to go. Any recommendation is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Use some hardcoded access tokens in the apps - looks very unsafe and I don't know if it is possible.
=> It is not hardcoded :) In magento web-API when you pass user name and password then it generates token for that specific customer (Which is only valid for 1 hour - configurable from admin